# insert data from mysql to facebook

Tags: mysql, facebook

I created a facebook fanpage wich shows different content to nonfan and fan. Fans have registrated to mysql so I want them to see a personal content.

Therefore I need to insert data from my own database. I tried to do this and added the following code to the index.php:

```
require_once ".src/dbdata.php";
```

But then the page cannot be displayed. Can anybody tell me how I can do this?

Comment: Is it the good path to the file, did you check the rights of the file ?

Comment: read rights in file .src/dbdata.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dbdata.php I had the following code :

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbname";
$dbuser = "dbuser";
$dbpass = "dbpass";

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
```

To get this work I cut `mysql_connect`and `mysql_select_db` off and inserted these two lines in the content-page.